# Admob crashes app with NullPointerException in DeviceMotionService

Tags: android, webview, admob

Our app gets lots of NullPointerExceptions in DeviceMotionService. We don't have a WebView in our app; it seems this is related to the Admob SDK. How can I work around the problem to prevent crashes?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.DeviceMotionService$2.run(DeviceMotionService.java:103)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:734)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

DeviceMotionService.java is part of the Android SDK. This doesn't appear to be something I can fix using the answers at [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: please show code in your ad activity

Comment: That is the problem, I don't have WebView I don't have any code related to WebView other than admob itself.

Comment: Looks like it is caused by admob (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54877) in your case. Did you find a work-around?